# What is the equivalent of `ADD-CORRESPONDING` in ABAP Objects?

Tags: oop, abap

With the below executable program, there is the following syntax error:

> "ADD-CORRESPONDING" is not supported in the OO context

What is the equivalent of `ADD-CORRESPONDING` in ABAP Objects?

```
REPORT.
CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION FOR TESTING RISK LEVEL HARMLESS DURATION SHORT.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS main.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_struc1,
             number1 TYPE i,
             number2 TYPE i,
           END OF ty_struc1,
           BEGIN OF ty_struc2,
             number1 TYPE i,
             number3 TYPE i,
           END OF ty_struc2.
    DATA(struc1) = VALUE ty_struc1( number1 = 1 number2 = 1 ).
    DATA(struc2) = VALUE ty_struc2( number1 = 1 number3 = 1 ).
    ADD-CORRESPONDING struc1 TO struc2.
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals( act = struc2 exp = VALUE ty_struc2( number1 = 2 number3 = 1 ) ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_app=>main( ).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can code the equivalent logic yourself. There's a test code to demonstrate how it works. This code compiles in 7.40 SP08:

```
CLASS lcx_add_corresp_not_all_struct DEFINITION INHERITING FROM cx_static_check.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS add_corresponding IMPORTING from_struct TYPE any
                                    CHANGING  to_struct   TYPE any
                                    RAISING   lcx_add_corresp_not_all_struct
                                              cx_sy_conversion_overflow.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD add_corresponding.
    TYPES: ty_names            TYPE HASHED TABLE OF abap_compname WITH UNIQUE KEY table_line,
           ty_names_in_structs TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_names WITH EMPTY KEY,
           ty_table_rtti       TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF REF TO cl_abap_typedescr WITH EMPTY KEY.
    DATA(rtti_from_struct) = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( from_struct ).
    DATA(rtti_to_struct) = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( to_struct ).
    IF rtti_from_struct->kind <> rtti_from_struct->kind_struct
        OR rtti_to_struct->kind <> rtti_to_struct->kind_struct.
      RAISE EXCEPTION NEW lcx_add_corresp_not_all_struct( ).
    ENDIF.
    DATA(names_in_structs) = VALUE ty_names_in_structs(
        FOR rtti IN VALUE ty_table_rtti( ( rtti_from_struct ) ( rtti_to_struct ) )
        ( VALUE #( FOR <comp> IN CAST cl_abap_structdescr( rtti )->components
                           WHERE ( type_kind CA '8abeFIPs' ) " all numeric types
                           ( <comp>-name ) ) ) ).
    DATA(same_names) = FILTER ty_names( names_in_structs[ 1 ] IN names_in_structs[ 2 ] WHERE table_line = table_line ).
    LOOP AT same_names REFERENCE INTO DATA(same_name).
      ASSIGN COMPONENT same_name->* OF STRUCTURE from_struct TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<from_number>).
      ASSERT sy-subrc = 0.
      ASSIGN COMPONENT same_name->* OF STRUCTURE to_struct TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<to_number>).
      ASSERT sy-subrc = 0.
      <to_number> = <to_number> + <from_number>.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ltc_app DEFINITION
      FOR TESTING
      DURATION SHORT
      RISK LEVEL HARMLESS.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    METHODS test FOR TESTING RAISING cx_static_check.
    METHODS overflow FOR TESTING RAISING cx_static_check.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS ltc_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD test.
    TYPES: ty_output LIKE ls_output.
    ls_output = VALUE #( clabs = 100 ceinm = 500 ).
    DATA(ls_output2) = ls_output.
    lcl_app=>add_corresponding( EXPORTING from_struct = ls_output2 CHANGING to_struct = ls_output ).
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals( act = ls_output exp = VALUE ty_output( clabs = 200 ceinm = 1000 ) ).
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD overflow.
    TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_struct,
             int1 TYPE int1,
           END OF ty_struct.
    DATA(from_struct) = VALUE ty_struct( int1 = 200 ).
    DATA(to_struct) = from_struct.
    TRY.
        lcl_app=>add_corresponding( EXPORTING from_struct = from_struct CHANGING to_struct = to_struct ).
      CATCH cx_sy_conversion_overflow INTO DATA(arithmetic_overflow).
    ENDTRY.
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_bound( act = arithmetic_overflow msg = |Actual: { to_struct-int1 } ; expected: arithmetic overflow| ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

NB: instead of `ADD-CORRESPONDING`, you may simply use `ls_output-clabs = ls_output-clabs + ls_mchb-clabs` and repeat for all numeric components.

NB: `ADD-CORRESPONDING` and other arithmetic "corresponding" statements were [made obsolete because they are considered error-prone](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapadd-corresponding.htm):

> "These statements are error-prone because, particularly in complex structures, it is not easy to check that identically named components have the data type and content necessary for a numeric operation."

Answer (score 1):

Just create form in subroutine pool for that and call it from class method via perform.